# how get number between two numbers in file already read in program

Tags: c#, string, substring

i tried to get number between 23 23 23 and 00 00.

for example i have line in text file as 23 23 23 45 45 00 00. 
how can i get 45 45 in string.
i tried as

```
public static string getBetween(string strSource, string strStart, int bytes)
{
    int Start = 0, End = 0;
    {
        Start = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, 0) + strStart.Length;
        End = Start + (bytes * 3) - 2;     //because we know the size of string
        return strSource.Substring(Start, End - Start);
    }
}
```

Comment: what are the rules to define what you want?  Skip 3 numbers then take two or go from the end back 4 numbers and take two or take the first two which are different?

Comment: please define the rules...

Answer (score 0):

Your `End` must be:

```
End = strSource.IndexOf("00 00");
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
string x = "23 23 23 45 45 00 00";

const string firstPattern = "23";
const string lastPattern = "00";

int idx1 = x.LastIndexOf(firstPattern);
int idx2 = x.IndexOf(lastPattern);

string result = (x.Substring(idx1 + firstPattern.Length, idx2 - idx1 - firstPattern.Length)).Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this implementation is more flexible as doesn't assume a fixed start/end strings length, but introduced a bit more complex approach, as it uses regular expressions.

```
public static string getBetween(string input, string start, string end)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(input, String.Format("{0}(.*?){1}", 
                            Regex.Escape(start), Regex.Escape(end)));
    if (match.Success)
        return match.Groups[1].Value;
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what the rules are here, I'm guessing you want "columns" 4 and 5.

```
string stringScr = "23 23 23 45 45 00 00";

string [] cols = stringScr.Split(" ");

string result=cols[3]+" "+cols[4];
```

note, this way also gives you them as "individual" numbers, which I think is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        String str = "23 23 23 45 45 00 00";
        int index1=str.LastIndexOf("23");
        int index2 = str.IndexOf("00");
        index2 -= 3;
        str=str.Substring(index1+3, index2 - index1).Trim();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to get the 2nd (or any other) set in a space separated list.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a specified set of values from a string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="set">The 1-based numbered set.  To get the second set, pass 2.</param>
    /// <param name="str">A space-separated string with all of the values</param>
    /// <returns>A space-separated string with the specified set of values.</returns>
    private static string GetNthSet(int set, string str)
    {
        string output = string.Empty;
        string[] parts = str.Split(' ');
        List<string> used = new List<string>();
        foreach (var part in parts)
        {
            if(!used.Contains(part))
            {
                used.Add(part);
            }
            if(used.Count == set)
            {
                output += part + " ";
            }
            else if(used.Count > set)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return output.Trim();
    }
```